# The navigation prop is missing for the navigator. in react-navigation you must set up your app container directly

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-native, expo

im try to get this code i found online working locally in visual code studio, but it only works online

this is the expo to the code and all the file, https://snack.expo.io/@git/github.com/israsotomayor/react-native-redux-shopping-cart-count

**and this is the link to my error:**

[image]

**shoppingCart.js file**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import HomeScreen from './containers/HomeScreen'
import ElectronicsScreen from './containers/ElectronicsScreen'
import BooksScreen from './containers/BooksScreen'
import ShoppingCartIcon from './containers/ShoppingCartIcon'
import CartScreen from './containers/CartScreen'
class ShoppingCart extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppStackNavigator />
        );
    }
}
export default ShoppingCart;

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Electronics: ElectronicsScreen,
    Books: BooksScreen,
    Cart: CartScreen
}, {
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'Shopping App',
            headerRight: (
                <ShoppingCartIcon />
            )
        }
    })

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

**app.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import ShoppingCart from './ShoppingCart'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ShoppingCart />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just checked and this structure should work properly :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet
} from "react-native";

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import HomeScreen from './containers/HomeScreen'
import ElectronicsScreen from './containers/ElectronicsScreen'
import BooksScreen from './containers/BooksScreen'
import ShoppingCartIcon from './containers/ShoppingCartIcon'
import CartScreen from './containers/CartScreen'

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Electronics: ElectronicsScreen,
    Books: BooksScreen,
    Cart: CartScreen
}, {
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'Shopping App',
            headerRight: (
                <ShoppingCartIcon />
            )
        }
    })



export default createAppContainer (AppStackNavigator);
```

copy paste and it should work !!!

Comment: Why u add more than one answer?